# detect if a combination of string objects from an array matches against any commands

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, pattern-matching, string-matching

Please be patient and read my current scenario. My question is below.

My application takes in speech input and is successfully able to group words that match together to form either one word or a group of words - called phrases; be it a `name`, an `action`, a `pet`, or a `time` frame.

I have a master list of the phrases that are allowed and are stored in their respective arrays. So I have the following arrays `validNamesArray`, `validActionsArray`, `validPetsArray`, and a `validTimeFramesArray`.

A new array of phrases is returned each and every time the user stops speaking.

```
NSArray *phrasesBeingFedIn = @[@"CHARLIE", @"EAT", @"AT TEN O CLOCK", 
                                @"CAT", 
                                @"DOG", "URINATE", 
                                @"CHILDREN", @"ITS TIME TO", @"PLAY"];
```

Knowing that its ok to have the following combination to create a command:

```
COMMAND 1: NAME + ACTION + TIME FRAME
COMMAND 2: PET + ACTION 
COMMAND n: n + n, .. + n

//In the example above, only the groups of phrases 'Charlie eat at ten o clock' and 'dog urinate'
//would be valid commands, the phrase 'cat' would not qualify any of the commands
//and will therefor be ignored
```

**Question**

What is the best way for me to parse through the phrases being fed in and determine which combination phrases will satisfy my list of commands?

**POSSIBLE solution I've come up with**
One way is to step through the array and have if and else statements that check the phrases ahead and see if they satisfy any valid command patterns from the list, however my solution is not dynamic, I would have to add a new set of if and else statements for every single new  command permutation I create.

My solution is not efficient. Any ideas on how I could go about creating something like this that will work and is dynamic no matter if I add a new command sequence of phrase combination?

Comment: An algorithm question like this may be better served by programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @rmaddy Have you any ideas? and alright then I will do. When should I be posting at that stackexachange opposed to this one?

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic versus http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I think what I would do is make an array for each category of speech (pet, command, etc).  Those arrays would obviously have strings as elements.  You could then test each word against each simple array using

```
[simpleWordListOfPets containsObject:word]
```

Which would return a BOOL result.  You could do that in a case statement.  The logic after that is up to you, but I would keep scanning the sentence using NSScanner until you have finished evaluating each section.

I've used some similar concepts to analyze a paragraph... it starts off like this:

```
while ([scanner scanUpToString:@"," intoString:&word]) {

        processedWordCount++;
        NSLog(@"%i total words processed", processedWordCount);

        // Does word exist in the simple list?
        if ([simpleWordList containsObject:word]) {
            //NSLog(@"Word already exists: %@", word);
```

You would continue it with whatever logic you wanted (and you would search for a space rather than a ",".

Comment: I appreciate you posting an answer but I dont think you've understood fully what it is im trying to do. Please have a look at my question, possible solution, and problem agian. What your solution does is iterate through the array of words and check if a word exists in one of the master arrays. That is not the part I have problems with. My problem is the logic in finding a group of phrases that possibly match a list of valid commands such as phrases in this order: `NAME + ACTION + TIME` is a valid command and should be processed as a comannd having been found.

Comment: Maybe I don't appreciate the scale of the challenge properly, but if words were categorized as type A, B, C, and D, for example, you could decide that AC and AD were valid, and put that in another simple array.  You can then test your discovered pattern and simplify into "AC" against that simple array of valid combinations.

Comment: I think youre onto something, now its the question of associating those arrays with those letters of the alphabet. NSDictionary is coming to mind, hmmm