# NSPredicate match some words not word to word

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsstring, nspredicate

I am taking some text from a UITextView and using NSPredicate to take that text and see if it matches the data in my data model and database. currently I have to type in exactly word by word to see if it matches. I am using it like this:

```
- (IBAction)viewResults:(id)sender {

NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Chapters" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entitydesc];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theverse CONTAINS[cd] %@",self.textViewVerse.text];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if(matchingData.count <=0)
{
    self.theResults.text = @"NO Verse found";
}
else {
    NSString *theVerse = nil;
    NSString *chapterNumber = nil;
    NSString *chapterName = nil;
    NSString *verseNumber = nil;



    for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData){
        theVerse = [obj valueForKey:@"theverse"];
        chapterNumber = [obj valueForKey:@"chapternumber"];
        chapterName = [obj valueForKey:@"chaptername"];
        verseNumber = [obj valueForKey:@"versenumber"];
    }

    self.theResults.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Chapter Name: %@ \n\nChapter Number: %@ \n\nVerse Number: %@ \n\nVerse: %@",chapterName, chapterNumber, verseNumber, theVerse];

}

}
```

So if I type in "His wealth and his children will not benefit him" and hit the viewResults button, it will find the verse in the database and display it with its relevant details. However, if I type in "His wealth and his children will not benefit himself" it will display "NO Verse found". Is there a way I can view the verse without having to type in word to word  or a word which does not match and still find what I want to find?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the discussion (particularly the comments) that I had on a somewhat similar question on [detecting combinations of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177259/detect-if-a-combination-of-string-objects-from-an-array-matches-against-any-comm/21177625#21177625)

In your case, you could map all similar words to a unique key, then search for combinations of keys.